# Is there a way to automatically delete any links put into a Google Sheet document?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

If it matters I'm using Google Forms to put the data into the spreadsheet

Comment: Have you examined Google Macros? https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-macros/

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes there is!

For your situation, a good idea is to make use of Apps Script. Apps Script is a powerful development platform which can be used to build web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with G Suite.

Therefore, you can write your own script in such a way that the links wanted are being deleted.

Moreover, another thing that can help you fulfill the task wanted is to take a look at [Apps Script triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), more particularly at the [`onFormSubmit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) one.

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
- [Event Objects Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
- [Installable Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [FormTriggerBuilder Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder).